# Log function call on new line in Java and C#

Tags: java, c#, logging, newline, stack-trace

I have a logging function in CSharp and Java that I use in walking the stack. How do I make each log print to a new line only. Below are my Java and CSharp Functions.

```
 public static void LogFunctionCall(String parameters){

        Object trace =  Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[3];
        android.util.Log.i("@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@" + trace.toString()+ "", parameters );
    }
```

the java version is this

```
 public static void LogFunctionCall(string parameters,
       [System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallerMemberName] string methodName = "",
       [System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallerFilePath] string sourceFilePath = "",
       [System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallerLineNumber] int sourceLineNumber = 0)
        {
            var stackFrame = new StackFrame(1);
            var callerMethod = stackFrame.GetMethod();
            var className = callerMethod.DeclaringType;
            System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine("CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC" + " " + className + " " + methodName + " " + sourceLineNumber + " " + parameters + "\n");
        }
```

I code on a windows machine.
Please where exactly do I need to place the new line character. I tried this

```
 public static void LogFunctionCall(String parameters){

        Object trace =  Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[3];
        android.util.Log.i("@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@" + trace.toString()+ "", parameters + "\n" );
    }
```

but I still saw some of the logs being clumped up on a single line.

Comment: In addition to the methods listed below, you could also try System.Environment.NewLine

Comment: @Kevin Your solution worked for the CSharp version still trying to find the one that'll work for the Java. Thanks

Comment: for java try System.getProperty("line.separator");

Answer (score 3):

Instead of `\n`, try `\r\n` (carriage return and newline). Some text editors will display differently, so the newline may be in there, but whatever app you're using to read the logs might not be displaying it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You could also try

```
System.lineSeparator();
```

I've seen instances where the /n won't work but the lineSep does.

Answer (score 0):

Also, because it hasn't been mentioned, `Environment.NewLine` will give you the new line character that is configured for the current environment.